# Python convert ndarray object to 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two types of results named idcs

a) idcs is a 2D numpy array

```
print(idcs[0:3,:])
[[  147.  -696. -1000. ...,  2275.  2718.  2206.]
 [  140.  -599.  -999. ...,  1824.  1982.  2084.]
 [ -528.  -291.   441. ...,  -189.   522.   942.]]
```

b) idcs is a 1D ndarray object of numpy arrays (different data here)

```
print(idcs[0:3]) 
[ array([ -20.95406189,   54.04593811,  136.04593811, ...,   -4.95406189,
        -88.95406189,  -87.95406189])
 array([  24.49842377,   11.49842377,  -17.50157623, ..., -100.50157623,
       -121.50157623, -106.50157623])
 array([ 460.3249115,  411.3249115,  124.3249115, ...,  -79.6750885,
        -72.6750885,   97.3249115])]
```

I want to convert the output of type b) into type a). How to do this?
Using np.vstack did NOT work:

ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Thanks, Heinz

Answer (score 0):

That error suggests that your arrays in the second case have different lengths. You can't vertically stack arrays that have different lengths. If you modify the arrays so that they all the same length, then vstack will work.